Custom Transformer model issue
import math
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader
from torch.optim.lr_scheduler import ReduceLROnPlateau
from tqdm import tqdm
import sentencepiece as spm

# Define PositionalEncoding, MultiHeadAttention, PositionwiseFeedforward,
# TransformerEncoderLayer, TransformerDecoderLayer, and Transformer classes
class PositionalEncoding(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, d_model, dropout=0.1, max_len=5000):
        super(PositionalEncoding, self).__init__()
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(p=dropout)

        pe = torch.zeros(max_len, d_model)
        position = torch.arange(0, max_len, dtype=torch.float).unsqueeze(1)
        div_term = torch.exp(torch.arange(0, d_model, 2).float() * (-math.log(10000.0) / d_model))
        pe[:, 0::2] = torch.sin(position * div_term)
        pe[:, 1::2] = torch.cos(position * div_term)
        pe = pe.unsqueeze(0).transpose(0, 1)
        self.register_buffer('pe', pe)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = x + self.pe[:x.size(0), :]
        return self.dropout(x)

class MultiHeadAttention(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, d_model, num_heads, dropout=0.1):
        super(MultiHeadAttention, self).__init__()
        assert d_model % num_heads == 0
        self.d_model = d_model
        self.num_heads = num_heads
        self.depth = d_model // num_heads

        self.query = nn.Linear(d_model, d_model)
        self.key = nn.Linear(d_model, d_model)
        self.value = nn.Linear(d_model, d_model)
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(dropout)

    def forward(self, query, key, value, mask=None):
        batch_size = query.size(0)
        seq_len = query.size(1)

        query = self.query(query).view(batch_size, seq_len, self.num_heads, self.depth).transpose(1, 2)
        key = self.key(key).view(batch_size, seq_len, self.num_heads, self.depth).transpose(1, 2)
        value = self.value(value).view(batch_size, seq_len, self.num_heads, self.depth).transpose(1, 2)

        scores = torch.matmul(query, key.transpose(-2, -1)) / math.sqrt(self.depth)

        if mask is not None:
            mask = mask.unsqueeze(1).unsqueeze(1)  # Ensure mask is broadcastable
            scores = scores.masked_fill(mask == 0, float('-inf'))

        attention_weights = F.softmax(scores, dim=-1)
        attention_weights = self.dropout(attention_weights)
        context = torch.matmul(attention_weights, value)
        context = context.transpose(1, 2).contiguous().view(batch_size, seq_len, self.d_model)
        return context, attention_weights


class PositionwiseFeedforward(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, d_model, d_ff, dropout=0.1):
        super(PositionwiseFeedforward, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(d_model, d_ff)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(d_ff, d_model)
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(dropout)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.dropout(F.relu(self.fc1(x)))
        x = self.fc2(x)
        return x

class TransformerEncoderLayer(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, d_model, num_heads, d_ff, dropout=0.1):
        super(TransformerEncoderLayer, self).__init__()
        self.self_attn = MultiHeadAttention(d_model, num_heads, dropout)
        self.ffn = PositionwiseFeedforward(d_model, d_ff, dropout)
        self.norm1 = nn.LayerNorm(d_model)
        self.norm2 = nn.LayerNorm(d_model)
        self.dropout1 = nn.Dropout(dropout)
        self.dropout2 = nn.Dropout(dropout)

    def forward(self, src, src_mask=None):
        src2, _ = self.self_attn(src, src, src, src_mask)
        src = src + self.dropout1(src2)
        src = self.norm1(src)
        src2 = self.ffn(src)
        src = src + self.dropout2(src2)
        src = self.norm2(src)
        return src

class TransformerDecoderLayer(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, d_model, num_heads, d_ff, dropout=0.1):
        super(TransformerDecoderLayer, self).__init__()
        self.self_attn = MultiHeadAttention(d_model, num_heads, dropout)
        self.src_attn = MultiHeadAttention(d_model, num_heads, dropout)
        self.ffn = PositionwiseFeedforward(d_model, d_ff, dropout)
        self.norm1 = nn.LayerNorm(d_model)
        self.norm2 = nn.LayerNorm(d_model)
        self.norm3 = nn.LayerNorm(d_model)
        self.dropout1 = nn.Dropout(dropout)
        self.dropout2 = nn.Dropout(dropout)
        self.dropout3 = nn.Dropout(dropout)

    def forward(self, tgt, memory, tgt_mask=None, memory_mask=None):
        tgt2, self_attention_weights = self.self_attn(tgt, tgt, tgt, tgt_mask)
        tgt = tgt + self.dropout1(tgt2)
        tgt = self.norm1(tgt)
        tgt2, src_attention_weights = self.src_attn(tgt, memory, memory, memory_mask)
        tgt = tgt + self.dropout2(tgt2)
        tgt = self.norm2(tgt)
        tgt2 = self.ffn(tgt)
        tgt = tgt + self.dropout3(tgt2)
        tgt = self.norm3(tgt)
        return tgt, self_attention_weights, src_attention_weights

class Transformer(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_encoder_layers, num_decoder_layers, vocab_size, d_model, num_heads, d_ff, dropout=0.1):
        super(Transformer, self).__init__()
        self.embedding = nn.Embedding(vocab_size, d_model)
        self.pos_encoder = PositionalEncoding(d_model, dropout)
        self.encoder_layers = nn.ModuleList([TransformerEncoderLayer(d_model, num_heads, d_ff, dropout) for _ in range(num_encoder_layers)])
        self.decoder_layers = nn.ModuleList([TransformerDecoderLayer(d_model, num_heads, d_ff, dropout) for _ in range(num_decoder_layers)])
        self.fc_out = nn.Linear(d_model, vocab_size)
        self.d_model = d_model

    def forward(self, src, tgt, src_mask=None, tgt_mask=None):
        src = self.embedding(src) * math.sqrt(self.d_model)
        src = self.pos_encoder(src)
        tgt = self.embedding(tgt) * math.sqrt(self.d_model)
        tgt = self.pos_encoder(tgt)

        for layer in self.encoder_layers:
            src = layer(src, src_mask)
        
        memory = src

        for layer in self.decoder_layers:
            tgt, _, _ = layer(tgt, memory, tgt_mask, src_mask)

        output = self.fc_out(tgt)
        return output

class ConversationDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, conversations, sp_model):
        self.conversations = conversations
        self.sp_model = sp_model

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.conversations)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        input_text, target_text = self.conversations[idx]
        input_tensor = self.sp_model.encode(input_text, out_type=int)
        target_tensor = self.sp_model.encode(target_text, out_type=int)
        return input_tensor, target_tensor

def pad_sequence(seq, max_len, pad_value):
    return seq + [pad_value] * (max_len - len(seq))

def collate_fn(batch, pad_token=0):
    input_seqs, target_seqs = zip(*batch)
    max_input_len = max(len(seq) for seq in input_seqs)
    max_target_len = max(len(seq) for seq in target_seqs)
    input_seqs = [pad_sequence(seq, max_input_len, pad_token) for seq in input_seqs]
    target_seqs = [pad_sequence(seq, max_target_len, pad_token) for seq in target_seqs]
    input_seqs = torch.tensor(input_seqs, dtype=torch.long)
    target_seqs = torch.tensor(target_seqs, dtype=torch.long)
    return input_seqs, target_seqs

def train_model(model, dataloader, num_epochs, learning_rate, vocab_size):
    optimizer = optim.AdamW(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate, weight_decay=0.01)
    criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss(ignore_index=0)
    scheduler = ReduceLROnPlateau(optimizer, 'min', patience=2, verbose=True)

    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        model.train()
        total_loss = 0
        pbar = tqdm(dataloader, desc=f"Epoch {epoch + 1}/{num_epochs}")
        for src, tgt in pbar:
            optimizer.zero_grad()

            src = src.transpose(0, 1)
            tgt_input = tgt[:, :-1].transpose(0, 1)
            tgt_output = tgt[:, 1:].transpose(0, 1)

            src_mask = generate_square_subsequent_mask(src.size(0)).to(src.device)
            tgt_mask = generate_square_subsequent_mask(tgt_input.size(0)).to(tgt_input.device)

            src_mask = src_mask.unsqueeze(0)
            tgt_mask = tgt_mask.unsqueeze(0)

            output = model(src, tgt_input, src_mask=src_mask, tgt_mask=tgt_mask)
            output = output.transpose(0, 1).contiguous().view(-1, vocab_size)
            tgt_output = tgt_output.contiguous().view(-1)

            loss = criterion(output, tgt_output)
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()

            total_loss += loss.item()
            pbar.set_postfix({'loss': total_loss / len(pbar)})
        
        scheduler.step(total_loss / len(dataloader))


def generate_square_subsequent_mask(sz):
    mask = (torch.triu(torch.ones(sz, sz)) == 1).transpose(0, 1)
    mask = mask.float().masked_fill(mask == 0, float('-inf')).masked_fill(mask == 1, float(0.0))
    return mask


def generate_response(model, sp_model, input_text, max_len=20):
    model.eval()

    with torch.no_grad():
        src_tokens = sp_model.encode(input_text, out_type=int)
        src_tensor = torch.tensor([src_tokens], dtype=torch.long)
        src_mask = (src_tensor != 0).unsqueeze(-2)

        memory = model.encoder(src_tensor, src_mask)
        
        # Start decoding with "<s>" token
        tgt_token = [sp_model.bos_id()]

        for i in range(max_len):
            tgt_tensor = torch.tensor([tgt_token], dtype=torch.long)
            tgt_mask = (tgt_tensor != 0).unsqueeze(-2)
            
            output = model.decoder(tgt_tensor, memory, tgt_mask, src_mask)
            output = torch.argmax(output, dim=-1)
            token = output[0, -1].item()
            
            if token == sp_model.eos_id():
                break
            
            tgt_token.append(token)

        output_text = sp_model.decode_ids(tgt_token)
        return output_text

# Load SentencePiece model
sp_model = spm.SentencePieceProcessor(model_file='m.model')

# Example conversation dataset
conversations = [
    ("hello how are you", "i am fine"),
    ("what is your name", "my name is bot"),
    ("how old are you", "i am 2 years old")
]

# Create dataset and dataloader
dataset = ConversationDataset(conversations, sp_model)
dataloader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=2, shuffle=True, collate_fn=collate_fn)

# Model parameters
num_encoder_layers = 6
num_decoder_layers = 6
vocab_size = sp_model.get_piece_size()  # Get actual vocab size from SentencePiece model
d_model = 512
num_heads = 8
d_ff = 2048
dropout = 0.1
learning_rate = 0.0001
num_epochs = 10

# Initialize and train the model
model = Transformer(num_encoder_layers, num_decoder_layers, vocab_size, d_model, num_heads, d_ff, dropout)
train_model(model, dataloader, num_epochs, learning_rate, vocab_size)

# Test inference
input_text = "hello how are you"
response = generate_response(model, sp_model, input_text)
print(f"Input: {input_text}\nResponse: {response}")

>>> %Run ai.py
/home/shaykhul/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/optim/lr_scheduler.py:28: UserWarning: The verbose parameter is deprecated. Please use get_last_lr() to access the learning rate.
  warnings.warn("The verbose parameter is deprecated. Please use get_last_lr() "
Epoch 1/10:   0%|          | 0/2 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/shaykhul/Desktop/ai.py", line 272, in <module>
    train_model(model, dataloader, num_epochs, learning_rate, vocab_size)
  File "/home/shaykhul/Desktop/ai.py", line 196, in train_model
    output = model(src, tgt_input, src_mask=src_mask, tgt_mask=tgt_mask)
  File "/home/shaykhul/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1532, in _wrapped_call_impl
    return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/shaykhul/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1541, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/shaykhul/Desktop/ai.py", line 137, in forward
    src = layer(src, src_mask)
  File "/home/shaykhul/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1532, in _wrapped_call_impl
    return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/shaykhul/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1541, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/shaykhul/Desktop/ai.py", line 87, in forward
    src2, _ = self.self_attn(src, src, src, src_mask)
  File "/home/shaykhul/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1532, in _wrapped_call_impl
    return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/shaykhul/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1541, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/shaykhul/Desktop/ai.py", line 55, in forward
    scores = scores.masked_fill(mask == 0, float('-inf'))
RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (13) must match the size of tensor b (2) at non-singleton dimension 4

I can't fix this error. I tried different approaches and even ChatGP, but it was not fixed. The error occurred due to MultiHeadAttention dimension begin mismatched. I want to build a simple personal chat-bot with an AI girlfriend. So please help me to fix the error. I want to make my own custom transformer model, and train it with my own custom data sets.

This issue has been discussed at https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/torch-optim-lr-scheduler-py-28-userwarning-the-verbose-parameter-is-deprecated/196634 too. And the solution given is

Don’t pass the verbose argument to the scheduler as explained in the warning.

and

.get_last_lr() is the new and recommended way to check the current learning rate. I don’t know enough about lightning and how they are printing the lr during the training.

like the warning you received suggested.
This is your problematic line: scheduler = ReduceLROnPlateau(optimizer, 'min', patience=2, verbose=True).
